# How to modify trac workflow from admin panel?

Tags: workflow, trac

I've got a trac system v0.12.3 on remote host (mysvn.ru) and I haven't any access to the file trac.ini.
And I have to modify trac workflow from admin panel. May be with the help of some plugins.
I have trac_ini_editor plugin there, but I can't remove current options with it, only add new ones.

What plugins can modify trac workflow from admin panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything of your workflow changes can be done in trac.ini. Use [TracIniAdminPanelPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracIniAdminPanelPlugin) to do that via web interface in case you only have remote access.

1. install [AdvancedTicketWorkflowPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AdvancedTicketWorkflowPlugin). Have `advancedworkflow.*
   = enabled` in your `[components]` section of trac.ini.
2. Have `workflow = ConfigurableTicketWorkflow,TicketWorkflowOpOwnerReporter` in your `[ticket]` section of trac.ini.
3. Define your own workflow in a new trac.ini section `[ticket-workflow]`. The wiki page of AdvancedTicketWorkflowPlugin will explain that in detail.

Comment: Using TracIniAdminPanelPlugin sounds like a good hint, but as far as I know AdvancedTicketWorkflowPlugin isn't needed if you just want to edit the Workflow from the web interface. Other web-based workflow editors are [TracWorkflowAdminPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracWorkflowAdminPlugin) and [WorkflowEditorPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/WorkflowEditorPlugin).